# Angular datatables not allowing to sort columns with server side processing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

I'm using **angular-datatables** with server side processing, and it is not allowing me to perform sorting on columns.

This is my **HTML**:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" datatable="" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" dt-options="dtOptions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th translate>NAME</th>
            <th translate>BASIC_UNIT</th>
            <th translate>STATUS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

This is my **JS** in the corresponding controller:

```
  $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withBootstrap()
    .withOption('order', [0, 'asc'])
    .withOption('ajax', {
      url: 'path/to/server/resource',
      type: 'POST'
    })
    .withDataProp('data')
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

  $scope.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0)
    .withOption('sName', 'name')

    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1)
    .withOption('sName', 'basic_unit')
    .withOption('bSearchable', false)
    .withOption('bSortable', false),

    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2)
    .withOption('sName', 'status')
    .withOption('bSearchable', false)
    .withOption('bSortable', false)
  ];
```

Does anyone know if I'm missing something?.

Answer (score 0):

You have server-side processing enabled with `.withOption('serverSide', true)`. In server-side processing mode filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed by a server.

See [full list of parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) sent by the client in server-side processing mode. Among others, there are:

> `search[value]` Global search value
>
> `columns[i][search][value]` Search value to apply to this specific column.

If you're not handling these parameters, then it will appear as if no sorting is performed.

The solution would be to either implement filtering, paging and sorting on the server-side or switch to client-side processing mode. In client-side processing mode data can still be retrieved from the server, but filtering, paging and sorting will be performed by jQuery DataTables plug-in.

See [Processing modes](https://datatables.net/manual/data#Processing-modes) for more information.

Comment: I am aware of what you just explained, I'm indeed sorting, filtering, and paging on the server. The problem is that my table headers are not allowing "clicks" to sort the columns.

Comment: @lcrespofalco, understood, that wasn't clear from the question. Otherwise your DataTables-related code looks fine. I assume you understand then, that only "Name" column is sortable. Also `translate` attribute on `<th>` looks out of place, are you sure it's supposed to be there?

Comment: Yep I think my question wasn't that clear. @gyrocode.com, yes I only want to sort by name, and yep "translate" is OK there, it is a directive from angular-translate for I18n. I haven't tried removing that directive, could that be the reason?

Comment: @lcrespofalco, angular-translate library may be altering the headers which could detach click event handlers, removing `translate` is worth a try. As a workaround, you can wrap text that needs to be translated in a `<span translate></span>` instead.

Comment: thanks @gyrocode.com, I'll give it a try and let you know, but it is weird that without server side processing everything was working well, even using that directive on headers.

Comment: @lcrespofalco, then if it worked before, I'm out of guesses.

Comment: Me too, haha, I'll let you know if I find out something, thanks for your help @gyrocode.com

Comment: @lcrespofalco, have you discovered anything?

Comment: the `translate` directive has nothing to do with the problem. Still can't find a solution!.